# C# - Trying to find remaining EventHandler preventing control from going out of scope

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, profiling

Long story short, I inherited a fairly complex application and I'm trying to track down a memory leak involving a form. Right now, every time the form is closed and a new one brought up, the old one remains in memory. I tracked down an issue with a static event owned and set by a control within the program (apparently, so long as the static event was set, no instance of that control was considered out of scope, even when no one else referred to said controls). Now, I'm trying to track down the remaining issue.

Using MemProfiler and ANTS Memory Profile, I've learned that the root execution path goes like this:

```
FormOpenWatch        <--       The item which remains active
System.EventHandler -- (this as Delegate)._target
System.Object[]
System.EventHandler -- (this as MultiCastDelegate)._invocationList
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList+ListEntry  --  handler
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList+ListEntry  --  next
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList+ListEntry  --  next
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList+ListEntry  --  next
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList+ListEntry  --  next
System.ComponentModel.EventHandlerList  --  head
PTU.MdiPTU  --  (this as Component).events        <--       The base application
```

Anyone have any insight for what I might be looking for? I've found a Shown event added with the base application, and ensured that it gets removed when the form is being disposed of, but that doesn't seem to have fixed the problem.

Much thanks for any help you can provide.

*Later Edit:* I have thought I've successfully solved this several times over now, and I'm still having issues. The problem seems to be stemming from my Plotter class (and various derived classes) having this "public static event MouseEventHandler MultiCursorMouseMove;" event. We have a "cursor" which displays the value and time of the graph at the mouse's location. Originally, this worked on one graph at a time, but a request was made to allow the user to toggle a mode where moving the mouse moved the plot across all of the displayed graphs. I wrote up an initial treatment hooking the EventHandlers in as the items were instantiated, and my partner across the pond rewrote it to use the static event, which gets assigned to each item on construction. His way is much more elegant and works better. All except that it's resulted in memory leaks. Using the memory profiling software has shown that every time I try to get rid of the form holding the plots, I'm left with a number of cases of "Disposed instance with direct EventHandler roots". In each of these, it shows that the object is either a Plotter, or an object pointed to by the Plotter. And, in each of these, the base link is that a MultiCursorMouseMove EventList points to these objects. I think that what's happening is that the Plotter is staying alive because it has this static event which in turn is linked to the Plotters. I have managed to verify that MultiCursorMouseMove is null through the debugger at a given point by virtue of my Dispose code removing the event for each Plotter, and yet running the profiler at that same point still shows this chain from MultiCursorMouseMove to these classes.

I'm out of ideas on how to fix this currently. Anyone?

Comment: Scan the Watch form for subscribing to events _outside_ itself.

Comment: Why do you call it a _static_ event?

Comment: public static event MouseEventHandler MultiCursorMouseMove;

Comment: This doesn't look like a static event, FormOpenWatch subscribed to a MdiPTU event.

Comment: It's in a Plotter control, which is contained upon a Panel which resides on a TabPage in a TabControl on FormWatchControl. Which is a bit of a mouthful, honestly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MdiPTU is the MDI parent form for your application, it sounds like FormOpenWatch might have subscribed to one of its events.  If it hasn't done so directly, you might find the subscription in a FormOpenWatch superclass, or perhaps even in other code that can wire up execution of a FormOpenWatch method from an MdiPTU event.

Comment: I did find one case where a parent class subscribed to the FontChanged event on MdiPTU, got really excited, but I've verified that it's getting removed off of the event list and still there's that reference holding on to it. On to the next idea... but thank you for the pointer in what will probably be the right direction.

Comment: @SeanDuggan: That wouldn't matter, you are confused as to how these references are stored.  When you subscribe to an event, the *subscribee* maintains a reference to the *subscriber*.  So in your example it wouldn't make a difference.  You need to find where the child form subscribes to events of objects that live longer than it does, not the other way around.

Comment: It's possible I am misunderstanding. To explain what I stated above, FormPTU, which is the parent class to FormShowDataPlot, which is the parent class to FormOpenWatch, has a reference to the MdiPTU instance named MainWindow. Within the FormPTU_Shown method, the following statement is run, "MainWindow.FontChanged += new System.EventHandler(ChangeFont);".

Which... now I'm starting to wonder if perhaps the problem is it's been added multiple times, although I don't know how to test for it.

Comment: On a side note, I rearranged the Cleanup method to remove an instance of the FontChanged event ("MainWindow.FontChanged -= new System.EventHandler(ChangeFont);") prior to MainWindow being set to NULL and for a bit there, it looked like the memory leak was gone, but it looks like it's just changed from a direct link from the EventHandler to an indirect one (at least according to the profiling tools mentioned above).

Comment: Try unsubscribing from the event in FormOpenWatch's Dispose method.

Comment: I don't know for certain if that was the correct answer (there was an earlier part of my code where an exception was being quietly ignored, preventing various changes from executing, meaning I don't know which of my fixes did the trick), but it certainly got me looking in the right direction. Thank you.