# How to completely remove all items for an event which is static

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, static, event-handling

I have a class, `Plotter`, which has a static event (declared `public static event MouseEventHandler MultiCursorMouseMove` for those wondering how I have a static event).

It emulates a graphical plot and our current application displays about 30-40 of them. The purpose of the event is to draw a cursor across all displayed graphs to indicate the value for the graph at the time the mouse cursor is pointing at.

The problem I'm running into is that, because the `Plotter` instances have this static event, they refuse to die. As best I can tell looking at them in a memory profiler, every instance of a `Plotter` (as well as the Form which contains them) is being held in memory by an `EventHandler` tied to this `MultiCursorMouseMove` event. I have coded set up which runs the `Dispose` method on each of the `Plotter` instances, which includes removing the delegate from `MultiCursorMouseMove`, but it doesn't seem to be doing any good. According to what I can see via the debugger, `Plotter.MultiCursorMouseMove` registers as null, but these instances still aren't getting collected and, best as I can tell via the profiler, all of the instances continue to exist due to `MultiCursorMouseMove`.

So, the question I have is, is there any way to explicitly state "remove all delegates associated with this event"?
I figure that way I'll be sure I got rid of all of them, not to mention it will simplify things compared to my current code which, during the `Dispose` method, cycles through all of the controls on the tab and runs `Dispose` on all of the `Plotter` objects it finds.

To be perfectly open, I [submitted this question last week](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8070094/c-sharp-trying-to-find-remaining-eventhandler-preventing-control-from-going-ou) but after saying it was solved, I found another issue. I tried editing the question, but it seems to have fallen out of public view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, the question I have is, is there any way to explicitly state
>   "remove all delegates associated with this event"?

Have you tried explicitly setting "MultiCursorMouseMove" to null?

Comment: I had. I got an error saying that the event would only take += or -=. I just made that change and indeed it removes all events. Unfortunately, it also completely breaks the multi-cursor functionality... the Dispose is being called right after the plots are displayed and removing all delegates from the static event results in no one updating as the mouse goes over them.

Comment: I have my solution implemented. I just needed to find the right time to remove those events. Thank you. That works.

Answer (score 1):

You could expand your event syntax to track add/remove calls to find out those objects which didn't not unsubscribe:

```
public static event MouseEventHandler MultiCursorMouseMove 
{
  add 
  {
  }
  remove
  {
  }
}
```

You could also follow [Weak event pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970850.aspx), or the [one described by J. Richter](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jeffreyr/archive/2011/03/17/weak-event-handlers.aspx). Weak handlers are based on weak references, which don't block GC.

And, at last, you could use hard-core Reflection approach to clean array of delegates in static MouseEventHandler object.

Comment: Excellent suggestions. I'll admit that I failed pretty utterly to understand the MSDN documentation of the Weak event pattern. J. Richter's might be more useful since it has actual example code. Ultimately, I took Erik's suggestion as it was the simplest solution, but thank you for the reference on the Weak event pattern. I'll have to read up on that.

Comment: @SeanDuggan - I've been thinking about why such a simple solution would work for a static field.. don't you doing something wrong from architectural point of view? I mean if you completely safely can reset static field, that means that there is no need in 'staticness', what do you think? Not sure about your app specific, but probably it'd better to store MultiCursorMouseMove handler in a parent form and then broadcast data to particular views? It's up to you of course :)